# How the teminal shell HostName can be as "229:~ lancee$"?

Tags: shell, networking, terminal, macbook

It prints :

```
"Last login: Tue Mar  1 17:19:48 on ttys000 ly-lanceedemacbook:~ lancee$ "
```

when I login terminal on my Macbook with networking.

But sometime go like this :

```
"229:~ lancee$"
```

random numbers, Is there any hackTools working within the local area network?
or means what?

Comment: What does `echo "$PS1"` say? What about `grep 'PS1' ~/.profile ~/.bashrc /etc/profile`?

Comment: If PS1 contains `\!` then the "random number" is the command history number.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that one of the networks you visit hands out hostnames that "reflect" your IP? I´ve seen this in practice before, where the hostname auto-assigned to your machine essentially is eg. `154.local` (or 154.example.com) given a DHCP-provided IP of `192.0.32.154` . Since you obviously use `\h` and not `\H` in your PS1 you would then only seem to have a random number as a hostname.
Network Admins tend to do that to shorten the amount of repetitive numbers they have to type (and various other reasons).